Can Panel support hosting Open3D as a local host website?
I am currently trying to create a Panel dashboard which contains a locally hosted website. Specifically using Open3D's web visualiser. Currently I can get the web visualiser to work and accessible on its own at localhost:8888. I can also get Panel to host its own website https://panel.holoviz.org/, however getting Panel to show the locally hosted website seems to just produce a white screen.
This is the code I currently have:
import open3d as o3d #0.18.0
import panel as pn #1.4.5
import numpy as np #1.26.3
import threading
print(o3d.__version__)
print(pn.__version__)
print(np.__version__)

def open3dvisualise(open3d_object):
    o3d.visualization.draw(open3d_object)

o3d.visualization.webrtc_server.enable_webrtc()
mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_sphere()
mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
vis_thread = threading.Thread(target=open3dvisualise, args=(mesh, ))
vis_thread.start()

html = """
<iframe src="localhost:8888" width="1600" height="800"></iframe>
"""#localhost:8888 #https://panel.holoviz.org/

markdown_pane = pn.pane.Markdown(html)

markdown_pane.servable()
markdown_pane.show()

If I replace localhost:8888 with https://panel.holoviz.org/, the website is correctly displayed within panel. However with localhost:8888 the frame is there but it is just blank with no content.
If I try http://localhost:8888, the page says that there was no response. As such I'm reasonably sure I have the right address and that is not causing the issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
